# List comprehension output in separate line

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to have each pair (key, value) printed on a separate line from this list comprehension,

```
print({'Doc. ' + k + '.txt: ':v for k, v in dict.items()})
```

Such as:

```
{'Doc. 23.txt: ': 0.027716832767124815,
 'Doc. 7.txt: ': 0.016852886586198594,
 'Doc. 17.txt: ': 0.014667013392619908,
 'Doc. 37.txt: ': 0.01410963740876677}
```

I tried concatenating '\n', which has no effect here.
Thanks for any assistance.

P.S: Using `pprint()` will disturb the order of the values which is unaffordable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
mydict = {23: 0.027716832767124815,
  7: 0.016852886586198594,
  17: 0.014667013392619908,
  37: 0.01410963740876677}

print('{' + ',\n'.join(
    ["'Doc. {}.txt': {}".format(k, v) for k, v in mydict.items()]
  ) + '}')
```

Pay attention to the square brackets inside the print. They denote list comprehension (while curly brackets are *dictionary* comprehension). In this code, you can replace list comprehension with generator comprehension (round brackets), with the same end result.

`',\n'.join(list)` inserts `',\n'` between the elements of the list, providing the result you asked for.

Comment: It worked! Highly appreciated. I'll give a read to generator comprehension.

Comment: Formally, they are called ["generator expressions"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

Answer (score 1):

You could make your own print/format function just for this:

```
def my_print_function(d, prefix="", suffix=""):
    print("{", end="")
    for i, (k, v) in enumerate(d.items()):
        if i == 0:
            print("'{}{}{}': {},".format(prefix, k, suffix, v))
        else:
            print(" '{}{}{}': {},".format(prefix, k, suffix, v))
    print("}")

my_print_function(my_dict, "Doc. ", ".txt: ")

# {'Doc. 23.txt: ': 0.027716832767124815,
#  'Doc. 7.txt: ': 0.016852886586198594,
#  'Doc. 17.txt: ': 0.014667013392619908,
#  'Doc. 37.txt: ': 0.01410963740876677,
# }
```

As far as I am aware, you won't be able to do this with a comprehension. Also, you should avoid naming things `dict` as this overwrites the `dict` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries have no order, so if you want keys sorted as `[23, 7, 17, 37]`, you could do something like:

```
>>> import json
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>>
>>> order = ["23", "7", "17", "37"]                                                                                                                                                                               
>>> d = {                                                                                                                                                                                                         
...     "23": 0.0277,                                                                                                                                                                                             
...     "7": 0.0168,                                                                                                                                                                                              
...     "17": 0.0146,                                                                                                                                                                                             
...     "37": 0.0141                                                                                                                                                                                              
... }                                                                                                                                                                                                             
>>> sorted_d = OrderedDict([("Doc." + k + ".txt:", d[k]) for k in order])                                                                                                                                         
>>> print(json.dumps(sorted_d, indent=4))                                                                                                                                                                         
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    "Doc.23.txt:": 0.0277,                                                                                                                                                                                        
    "Doc.7.txt:": 0.0168,                                                                                                                                                                                         
    "Doc.17.txt:": 0.0146,                                                                                                                                                                                        
    "Doc.37.txt:": 0.0141                                                                                                                                                                                         
}
```

Comment: Starting from Python 3.6, dictionaries are ordered, although it's a result of a particular optimization of the underlying data structured and is not guaranteed to stay forever.

Comment: I don' know what python version he is on. Anyways, I think you should pay attention if interested in keys order